# Erro ao executar um trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estou com um problema num trigger qué quando eu faço um insert de um registo quero que automaticamente passe um valor que vem por default está 1 para 0 só que está sempre a dar este erro.

**Can't update table 'recibos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER actrecibo AFTER INSERT on Recibos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
        UPDATE recibos set is_new = 0 WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```

Alguém sabe o procurar de isto acontecer e como posso resolver ?

Comment: De acordo com essa resposta não é permitido fazer isso. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o contexto da utilização da Trigger, porém analisando apenas o código percebi o seguinte.

Após o `INSERT` você está atualizando o campo `is_new = 0` do registro que acabou de inserir.

Se for isso você pode tentar assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actrecibo BEFORE INSERT on Recibos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
      SET NEW.is_new = 0;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que com BEFORE você consegue isso.

```
CREATE TRIGGER actrecibo BEFORE INSERT on Recibos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
      SET NEW.id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM Recibos ) + 1
END
```